# how to set state values on conditional basis inside Constructor in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, constructor, lifecycle, setvalue

I am working with react js. I need the solution for one of the issues that I am facing-
I wanted to set conditional value to the this.state properties inside constructor.

Below is the Constructor code-

```
    constructor(props) {        
       super(props)   
       this.state = {
          A: 0
       }
    }
```

And I have to set the values for this.state property (A) on conditional basis. Like below-

```
    if (a !== null && a !== 'undefined') {
        this.setState({ ...this.state, A: a })
    }
    else if (b !== null && b !== 'undefined') {
        this.setState({ ...this.state, A: b })
    }
```

So my question is how we can set the this.state properties on conditional basis or is there any life cycle hook where I can set the state values. But the values should be updated while page is loading only and not after the page load.

Like, I tried with ComponentDidMount() hook but its not setting the state value at page load.

Note: There is a possibility here, above if-else condition both can false. In this case state value can be empty/null/0.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check when set state right?

`this.state = { A: a !== null && a !== 'undefined' ? a : 0,  B: b !== null && b !== 'undefined' ? b : 0 }`

This or something simpler like
`this.state= {A: a ?? 0, B b ?? 0 }`